# Determine where UITextView will truncate string

Tags: ios, string, swift, autolayout, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` with a long string. The text views size is determined by autolayout, and it is set to tail truncate the text. It looks like this:

[image: UITextView truncating]

**How can I determing the range of the string that is displayed and the range that is truncated away?**

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
class ViewController: UIViewController ,NSLayoutManagerDelegate{

@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
var range :NSRange!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    textView.textContainer.layoutManager?.delegate = self
    let str = textView.text as NSString
    //Regardless of the repeated string
    range = str.rangeOfString("cillium adipisicing")
    print(range)


}

// Invoked while determining the soft line break point.  When NO, NSLayoutManager tries to find the next line break opportunity before charIndex
func layoutManager(layoutManager: NSLayoutManager, shouldBreakLineByWordBeforeCharacterAtIndex charIndex: Int) -> Bool{

    // charIndex is in the string or not
    if range.location != NSNotFound && NSLocationInRange(charIndex, NSRange(location: range.location + 1, length: range.length - 1 )) {
        print("range of string is truncated -> charIndex is \(charIndex)")
    }
    return  true
}
}
```

but it's limited to  `BreakLineByWord` if words without " " and truncated ，`charIndex is 0`

hope it be helpful :)

Answer (score -1):

**Swift 5** for an *NSAttributedString* text property

```
extension UITextView {  

   var attributedTextTruncated: Bool {
      guard let attributedText = self.attributedText else {
        return false
      }
      let attributedTextSize = attributedText.size()
      return attributedTextSize.width > self.bounds.width
   }

}
```